# Comparing the perfect groups of order 1344

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, latin-square

Take two nonisomorphic perfect groups of order 1344 and label the elements of each with the numbers 1 through 1344, then superimpose their respective Cayley tables (for simplicity’s sake, the *n*th row and *n*th column should correspond to element *n*). What is the lowest possible number of mismatched entries?

Comment: I am dying to know how this question arose!

Comment: I was wondering about how similar two groups of the same “shape” really are.

Comment: The only cardinal of a nonabelian simple group dividing $1344$ is $168$, and $1344=168\times 8$. Since the Out of a group of order 8 has order $<168$, the only possibility will be a central extension. But the Schur multiplier of the simple group of order 168 has order 2. So I don't see how a perfect group of order 1344 could exist.

Comment: There are two isomorphism classes of perfect groups of order $1344$. They are the split and the nonsplit extensions of $L_3(2)$ by the natural module.

Comment: @YCor The Out of an elementary abelian group of order $8$ has order exactly $168$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oops, thanks. So the correct conclusion is that it amounts to classify the extensions of $V=C_2^3$ by $L=\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbf{F}_2)$ (with the standard action), so this is essentially a cohomology computation (namely of $H^2(L,V)$). If this $H^2$ has order 2 this means 2 isomorphism classes (which is what Dave says). (If it's larger, then one has to classify isomorphic groups for distinct cohomology classes, which probably amounts to check $\mathrm{Out}(L)$-orbits in this $H^2$.)

Comment: It is hard to envisage how this problem could be solved without a massive computer calculation, which at first sight requires checking all $1344!$ possible mappings. In the end you might have to settle for an approximate answer.

Comment: @YCor Actually it's not quite like that. There are two isomorphism classes of three dimensional module for $L_3(2)$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$, but they're interchanged by the outer automorphism. So you just have to choose one and compute $H^2$, which is one dimensional.

Comment: @DaveBenson but it amounts to the same when you observe that the quotient group has to be the whole automorphism group. So, you know in advance what the group is and how it acts.

Comment: The point I was making is that Out($L$) doesn't act on $H^2(L,V)$.